# How to read file's content from GitHub file with a specific branch name?

Tags: python, git, github

In branch name, `qa03`, in my repository, `repo1`, I have a file, `environment.yml`.

The content of `environment.yml` is following:

```
# This is chef config file

chef:
  - xxx/chef
  - xxx/faster-git-clone
bam:
  - xxx/asd
  - V20180820_902
```

**I want to read this whole file from my python script and store it into my string** (so that I can send it to my Trello Card).

Q: How do I read the content of the file from GitHub repo with specific branchname? (below is my pseudocode)

```
....
# Read `environmet.yml from repo1/qa03`, and send it to Trello.
string_content = read('repo1:qa03/environment.yml') #Q: how???
send(string_content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get branch by modifying the following part of the url:

```
https://github.com/username/repositoryName/blob/branchName/path/to/file
```

or in your case:

```
string_content = read(https://github.com/username/repo1/blob/qa03/environment.yml)
send(string_content)
```

Comment: Jonelinuas I don't get it

Comment: I'm getting this error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: `

Comment: Github uses `/blob/` in their url when returning a single file. Here's an example of a `.gitignore` file in a `2.1.x` branch of a random github repository `https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.1.x/.gitignore` You would need to adjust the link to fit your particular repository (P.S. sorry for a late reply)